# Will inventory stock be retained if advanced stock management is disabled in existing Prestashop 1.6.1.4 installation?

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I have a store that has over 16,000 product records with the quantities tab configured with "I want to use the advanced stock management system for this product." checked and "I want to specify available quantities manually." also checked. I assume this second bit bypasses entry into the warehouse table.

The question is, what are the consequences, if any, for setting "Enable advanced stock management" to NO at this point?

I think I remember this will also set "New products use advanced stock management" to NO as well.

But much more importantly, will inventory have to be retaken and entered, or will the existing values be moved/retained in the "classic" quantity box found in the quantities tab?